# Weird behavior of Path.toFile()

Tags: java, java-7

When I try doing `Path.toFile()` Where path is C:,  for some reason the resulting file is defaulting to current executing directory instead.

I am executing from within a directory in C:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);   
System.out.println("Enter directory to be scanned: ");//I pass C:   
Path inputPath = Paths.get(userInput.nextLine());   
inputPath.toFile(); //this was defaulting to current execution directory
```

However when I tried passing `"C:\\\\"` that seems to have solved the problem. Why?

Comment: Why don't you show us the exact code where you're using the toFile() method?

Comment: Try with `Paths.get("c:\\").toFile()` instead

Comment: Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter directory to be scanned: ");//i pass C:

  Path inputPath = Paths.get(userInput.nextLine());
inputPath.toFile();

However when i tried passing "C:\\" that seems to have solved the problem. Why?

Comment: @KiranK add the code to the question

Comment: I think it's a historical thing. In DOS shell COMMAND.COM, C: was not a path but a disk selector, whereas C:\ was the path to the root of C.

Answer (score 4):

That's what `C:` *means* on Windows. When used as a path, it refers to the current working directory on the C drive. (On Windows, each drive has a different current working directory.) Similarly, something like `C:file.txt` refers to `file.txt` within the current working directory of the C drive. If you want to refer to the root of the drive, that's `C:\`.

However, calling [`toFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--) should not cause this, as the documentation says:

> Where this `Path` is associated with the default provider, then this method is equivalent to returning a `File` object constructed with the `String` representation of this path.

The method seems to works correctly when I run this program:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:");
File f = p.toFile();
System.out.println(p);
System.out.println(f);
```

The output is `C:` on both lines.

If the string representation of the `File` object you are getting is not the same as the string representation of the `Path`, then this is a bug in your version of Java.

Otherwise, this is a misunderstanding, and the `toFile()` method is correctly returning a `File` object referring to `C:`. But when you *use* the object to access things, it will access the current working directory. So would using the `Path` object. Whichever object you use, it's behaving correctly.